# can't import opencv in PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I've tried to import opencv to Pycharm, but this error pops up:

Collecting cv2

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2

Can you please help me?

Comment: What is the opencv version that you want to install?

Comment: I just wrote pip install opencv-python into the command line, should i specify the version?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `opencv` with:

   pip3 install opencv-python
2. Make sure you are using the correct interpreter for your project in PyCharm. Go to *File\Settings...\Project\Project Interpreter* and ensure `opencv` is listed under the Python interpreter you wish to use.

Comment: its not listed there, but when I run pip3 install opencv-python this is what i've got:

Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\zolibil37\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.2.0.32)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\zolibil37\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.1)

Comment: Ok, do you have more than one interpretor in the Interpreter list? Check the packages for all if yes.

Comment: Yes, there is like 20 interpretors.

Comment: Are you sure? I am referring to the dropdown list where it says "Python 3.x..." not the list of packages under that. I hope you don't have 20 versions of Python installed :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. There is only one Python3.8(venv)

Comment: No worries. If you installed Python 3.8 in a virtual environment, then you need to install packages in that venv as well. Please activate the virtual environment then install opencv there.

Comment: What do you mean by activate the virtual environment?

Comment: The "venv" in "Python3.8(venv)" indicates you have a virtual environment,  and if you want to use Python in that virtual environment, then any package you wish to use needs to be installed in the venv. How did you install Python? Did you follow a tutorial?

Comment: I've tried it with condo but still nothing. I've got the same error message, I can import every libraries except the openCv, and even if i import a new library which I havent used before I can install it to my project and use it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using python 3.8. Opencv still not applicable for python 3.8. In your situation, I recommend you to use python 3.7.

Steps:

```
1. uninstall the current python.

2. Install python 3.7. 

3. Add it to the path. 

4. When you create a new project make sure to use Python 3.7 as shown below:
```

[image: Python3.7]

Finally, Good luck. ^_*